# How can I call HttpUrlConnection disconnect()

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection, nshttpurlresponse

My code sends HttpConnection and then tries to use either `connection.getInputStream()` or `connection.getErrorStream()` to deserialize response.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // getErrorStream()
String content = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

How can I pass connection to `parse(HttpURLConnection connection)` function and call `connection.disconnect()` after it's finished()?

I was thinking about

```
connection.disconnect();
return MyObject.fromString(connection.getInputStream(), connection.getErrorStream());
```

but not sure whether it makes sense to disconnect before reading the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String content = parse(connection);
connection.disconnect();
// do something with content
```